# Enable css module in react 16.7

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react looking videos but in one video they are enabling css module by eject>edit  webpack.config.dev.js but i can't find the same file in my react , later i came to know that in 16.7 its different so can anyone tell the steps to enable css module in react 16.7

Comment: It's a webpack configuration, so it shouldn't matter which react version you have. After ejecting, search die sub directories of your project for files named like webpack*.js

Comment: i found one but in that also there is different structure , so where to add Modules:true,
LocalIdentName: etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable CSS module, first of all go to your project directory then open command line and run `npm run eject`

inside the config folder you will find `webpack.config.dev.js` and `webpack.config.prod.js` files.open those files

and add this code to `webpack.config.dev.js`

```
{
  test: cssRegex,
  exclude: cssModuleRegex,
  use: getStyleLoaders({
    importLoaders: 1,
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
  }),
},
```

and in `filewebpack.config.prod.js` add

```
test: cssRegex,
exclude: cssModuleRegex,
loader: getStyleLoaders({
  importLoaders: 1,
  modules: true,
  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
  sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
}),
```

After saving this you can now use CSS module

Comment: ok i found first one but not the second one i.e config.prod.js ,  but it helped me thanks

Answer (score 4):

fortunately in react 16.8 no need to run "npm run eject" and you can just add extention ".module.css" in place of ".css" to get the sake of CSS module

Answer (score 0):

```
For react version 16.13
In webpack.config.js file find this keyword 'css-loader'.
You will find below code in line number 82 for react version-16.13
{
   loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
   options: cssOptions,      
}

Replace above object with 

{
   loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
   options: {
      modules: {
        mode: "local",
        localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]"
      },
      import: true,
      importLoaders: true
    }     
}

Start the server again by npm start(If changes are not reflected)
```